# Assigning a value to the same dates fulfilling a condition in a more efficient way in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe called `df1` that contains data for a number of regions in the column `NUTS_ID`:

[image]

The index, called `Date` has all the days of 2010. That is, for each code in `NUTS_ID` I have a day of 2010 (all days of the year for `AT1`, `AT2`and so on). I created a list containing the dates corresponding to non-workdays and I want to add a column that with 0 for non-workdays and 1 for workdays.

For this, I simply used a `for` loop that checks day by day if it's in the workday list I created:

```
for day in df1.index:
    if day not in workdays_list:
         df1.loc[day,'Workday'] = 0  # Assigning 0 to to non-workdays

    else:
         df1.loc[day,'Workday'] = 1  # Assigning 1 to workdays
```

This works well enough if the dataset is not big. But with some of the datasets I'm processing this takes a very long time. I would like to ask for ideas in order to do the process faster and more efficient. Thank you in advance for your input.

EDIT: One of the things I have thought is that maybe a `groupby` could be helpful, but I don't know if that is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `np.where` with `isin` to check if your Date (i.e. your index) is in the list you created:

```
import numpy as np
df1['Workday'] = np.where(df1.index.isin(workdays_list),1,0)
```

I can't reproduce your dataset, but something along those lines should work.